# I am trying to use redis zadd command with ZAddParams which is giving error

Tags: redis

when I am using zadd with ZAddparams
**long a = redisClient.zadd(“key”, 2.0, “member1”, ZAddParams.zAddParams().nx());**

I am getting “redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR bit offset is not a double or out of range”.

Although, **long a = redisClient.zadd(“key”, 2.0, “member1”)**; works completely fine
Can someone please help ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the version of Jedis that you are using and full stacktrace.

Comment: Also, are you sharing same Jedis object among multiple threads/classes/methods?